# How to add react-flexbox-grid with isomorphic-style-loader

Tags: webpack, react-starter-kit, isomorphic-style-loader, react-flexbox-grid

Any solution in solving this problem here using isomorphic-style-loader?
[kriasoft/react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/902)

Using the react-starter-kit, and the solutions they proposed here: [roylee0704/react-flexbox-grid](https://github.com/roylee0704/react-flexbox-grid/issues/28) doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to import your flexgrid css like so:

```
import grid from 'react-flexgrid/lib/flexgrid.css';
```

.
.
.

Then at the end you need to add imported styles to styles loader like this:

```
export default withStyles(grid, s)(Component)
```

But instead of package you link i use this one: https://github.com/nkt/react-flexgrid
Works for me.